# Footnote reference change to italics when I modify the Footnote text style to italics

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, footnote

I insert a footnote
I modify the footnote text style to italicize the font
Automatically change, only in the footnotes area, the Footnote reference style  to italic
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to change all footnotes in the document to Italic by using the Replace function.
Fill in ***^e*** in the **Find what** box, then select the **Replace with** box and click *More>Format>Font* to select **Italic**. Click OK and Replace All.

[image]

Comment: Thank you:
But the correct thing would be to do it through the styles and yet it does not work

Comment: @José Martínez Martínez Hi,The footnote reference area is independent of the style in the body text. Or you could try to create a new style of italics for footnotes in the text for easy use.

Comment: In the footer area, by default, Word uses two styles: Footnote reference for the reference and Footnote text for the text.

Comment: @José Martínez Martínez, you are right. But they have nothing to do with the text style of the body area.

Comment: Yes, the Footnote Text style works fine and can be modified. What happens is that the modifications that affect the size and style of the font are automatically transmitted to the Footnote Reference style, but only in the footnotes area.

Comment: I have posted the question to the Microsoft forum:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/footnote-reference-change-to-italics-when-i-modify/72028fc4-250e-4446-aab8-e2dc51f866ec

Comment: @José Martínez Martínez it seems that your problem has been correctly directed. Hope to have a nice week~